# curl_multi_exec not returning the entire response

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have the following code, but quite often the response is cut short and it fails to parse the XML. Is there a way to fix it?

```
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);
$ebayResponse = curl_multi_getcontent($ebayRequest);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ebayRequest); //close the handles
try {
  $ebay = simplexml_load_string($ebayResponse);
} catch (yii\base\ErrorException $e) {
  Yii::error("Could not parse EBay XML response. $e");
  Yii::error("Could not parse EBay XML response, \$ebayResponse: $ebayResponse");
```

I'm seeing many of these error in the logs

```
Could not parse EBay XML response. exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag tim line 1' in /app/controllers/ShoppingController.php:97 Context
Could not parse EBay XML response. exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag shippingType line 1' in /app/controllers/ShoppingController.php:97 Context
```

Ok I added more logging and this is the complete response from Ebay: http://pastie.org/private/wrucbjdaftuusskbzlzwq . Notice the last tag is not closed, so the response is being truncated somehow.

Comment: Can you grab the `$ebay` string contents from within the catch and output it somehow such as `file_put_contents` then tell us the contents of the XML file which is failing to be parsed?

Comment: @Ultimater Ok updated with more logging.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the behavior you've described. If `simplexml_load_string` is given a malformed string, it should return false and generate an E_WARNING. It does not raise an exception that is useful for try-catch to use. Make sure the error file and error line match the line you've given us. Try isolating the problem to as little code as possible. I understand you're saying it's getting truncated, but even with the truncated string, it shouldn't be causing the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @Ultimater The problem happens intermittently. It often works, but I see these exceptions in the logs after thousands of requests. It certainly throws an exception. Maybe Yii is doing something to make it an exception instead of a warning. Nevertheless, the problem isn't `simplexml_load_string`, the problem is with `curl_multi_getcontent` not returning the entire contents of the request. Less you think the problem is with EBay, the other request which is part of the multi-request to another service also gives an error for empty content, when it should return JSON.